# Why isn't my content binding which was working on pre2 not working on RC

Tags: ember.js

I had the following code in my pre 2

```
router.get('contentWithToolbarController').connectOutlet('toolbar', 'toolbar', {
    x1ButtonsVisible: true,
    x2ButtonsVisible: true,
    x3ButtonsVisible: true,
    x4ButtonsVisible: true
});
```

which was binding the 'toolbarController' content properly and the template/view would reflect the this data..

Now I am trying to to something similar in RC by setting the content of the toolbarController in setupController, so I have

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var toolbarController = this.controllerFor('toolbar');
        toolbarController.set('content', {
            x1ButtonsVisible: true,
            x2ButtonsVisible: true,
            x3ButtonsVisible: true,
            x4ButtonsVisible: true
        });
})
```

But this doesn't work and the view doesn't update according to these settings.

What I am doing wrong? Which of my assumptions are wrong?

Comment: how do you bind properties? can you update your question with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `this.controllerFor` any more.

Is this `setupController` that we see the `App.ToolbarRoute`? If so, you can set the content on the `controller` instance from the function's arguments.

If it isn't, then you'll need to use `needs` to set-up the other controller:

**Router**

Instruct the controller to call the `setupToolbar` method on the controller every time we move into this route.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.setupToolbar();
    }
});
```

**Controller**

With the `needs` to tell the `IndexController` what it requires, and the `setupToolbar` to actually set-up your toolbar. This is where the responsibility should lie for setting up another controller that is related to `IndexController`.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['toolbar'],
    setupToolbar: function() {
        var toolbarController = this.get('controllers.toolbar');
        toolbarController.set('content', {
            x1ButtonsVisible: true,
            x2ButtonsVisible: true,
            x3ButtonsVisible: true,
            x4ButtonsVisible: true
        });

        // Is it true?
        console.log(toolbarController.get('content.x1ButtonsVisible'));
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pBUK7/

The reason for this change is that the `IndexRoute` should **not** be responsible for setting up other controllers that aren't `IndexController`. If you really need this functionality, it should be done in the `IndexController` itself as we're doing above.

Comment: i am quite confused now. 
the latest guides specifically use "controllerFor", see http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/ 

i was able to fix the problem. 

my assumption was that controllerFor, returned the controller setup in the renderTemplate function, but that's not the case, actually setupController is triggered before renderTemplate.
i modified my renderTemplate to associate the controller of my toolbar template with a call to   this.controllerFor('toolbar').

of course this could be an unwilling hack. i'll go over the details of your response too.

Comment: That sounds very confusing.

Comment: my original app has templates embedded within templates through outlet. there is no toolbar route because it is an template within a template within a template for a given route. so i need to set it up within a route and setup all the different template/outlet/controllers for the different elements of the view for that given route.

are you sure that "controllerFor" is not supported? 

also i don't see the "needs" property documented in the latest API documentation, i looked at "Ember.Controller" and "Ember.ControllerMixin", have you seen it documented somewhere else?

Comment: I think the documentation was not updated yet. "controllerFor" still works but gives you warning about its deprecation in later versions.

Comment: i am about to lose my mind :) -- i don't see it deprecated in the source code? https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js, it is defined around line 314.

Comment: @machunter: I think you're right. From looking at the source code it appears to me that the `controllerFor` in the `ControllerMixin` is **@deprecated**, but as of yet the `controllerFor` you're referring to isn't. I suppose it's worth asking whether you could simplify your process somewhat? Because I get an inkling that you're over-complicating matters.

Comment: @machunter https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/packages/ember-application/lib/ext/controller.js, line 59.

Comment: @Wildhoney i am unclear on what needs does?  also my toolbar is used in different views, therefore it has its own controller. and when i use it in several views, i set it up in an outlet with its own controller. i don't let the controller of the main containing the toolbar control the toolbar. are you suggesting otherwise?

Comment: since i have a feeling that my question is related to a poor application architecture on my part, i'll accept @Wildhoney's answer. As for the controllerFor being deprecated, the ember team have stated that the API wouldn't change until 2.0, so for now i am assuming it is safe to use it at least until that version.